# Grails webflow - redirect to payment gateway and resume

Tags: spring, grails, spring-webflow, grails-webflow

I am creating a flow, where user would be redirected to a payment service and when he returns back to flow after completing payment,the flow should be resumed to next step.

Graild docs says, redirect ends the flow. 
Is there a way to achieve this with grails web flow ?

How could this be done in pure spring webflow otherwise.

Comment: Can you split the webflow into two?  The before payment and the after payment. Since webflow shares session and you are redirecting to an outside entity/site ending the pre payment webflow and starting an after payment webflow would be much better performance wise.

Comment: Yeah, i think i can do this, but i am trying to figureout, if its possible at all, what i am asking.